# How Do I Add A Vertical Scrolling TextView To An Android WIdget

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I have a widget that goes with my app, and in my xml I have a textview. My textview has multiple lines that end up going off the bottom of the widget.

How can I make my textview **vertically** scrollable, keeping in mind that it is in a widget?

Answer (score 0):

As a scrollable content, android widgets only support vertical scroll and it's limited to these views: `ListView`, `GridView` and `StackView` (Android 3.0 +)

Comment: @user2719774 if there is I couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

You define a fixed height/max height property to you textview and set multiline property to true.

Now you add text in multiple lines and when it reaches it's max height, it won't expand and you will see that the text on top will go out of the textview widget box and you can scroll it now.

You don't have to do anything to make it scrollable because it is a scrollable widget.

Comment: What widget? I am telling you textview behavior. You want textview to scroll vertically right? It will if you give a fixed height to it otherwise it will just keep expanding way beyond the device screen

Comment: I am sorry. My question might not have been clear. What I had is a **homescreen** widget for my application and I wanted it to have a scrolling text view to display on it, but I couldn't find a way how and scrollviews are not supported in homescreen widgets. I tried your answer, but what happened was that the textview's text ran off the bottom of the screen and when I tried to scroll down, the widget wouldn't let me.

Comment: That is what i am saying to stop the textview to ran off the botton of the screen, give it a fixed height. A fixed height will ensure that your textview does not wander off the bottom of the screen